# How can I have a globally (across entire container) unique constraint in Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, unique-constraint

Suppose I want to store the data that looks like the following

```
type Person = {
    Name:string
    PassportNumber:string
}

type PolicyStatus =
    |SaleInProgress
    |PolicyActive
    |Cancelled

type Policy = {
    PincipalPerson: Person
    PolicyDependents: Person list
    PolicyId:int
    PolicyState:PolicyStatus
}
```

(I've expressed these types as F# records since they look a lot like json but don't let that distract you)

I want to make it so that each person that features in a `Policy` is unique. This means, for example, if someone is a principal on some policy, they cannot also be a dependent on some other policy.

So if I store these in a `Policy` collection then I don't think there is a way to specify that the union of dependents and principals should have unique passport ids, is there?

If I was using some RDMS, then I can just keep people on a different table, have a foreign key between `Policy` and `People` and a unique constraint on `PassportNumber`.

So what is the idiomatic "NoSQL" way of doing this in Cosmos DB?

Comment: Can you formulate your uniqueness constraints more precisely?

Comment: @MoB. If I take every person that is a principal into an array, and every person that is a dependent into another array, then concatenated those arrays, the resulting array should contain people with unique passport ids. There should be no duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to enforce the uniqueness constraints you require directly in Cosmos DB, at least not if your data is structured as you proposed it. The uniqueness constraints that Cosmos DB supports are based on (combinations of) whole property values (e.g. first name + last name, or `PassportNumber`), so you can't look into an array of values.

If you do want to enforce the uniqueness constraints on the DB level and are willing to change your data model, consider embedding the policy inside the person object:

```
type Person = {
  Name: string
  PassportNumber: string              // with uniqueness constraint
  IsPrincipalPerson: Nullable<bool>   // specifies if the person is principal or dependent
  PolicyId: Nullable<int>
  PolicyState: Nullable<PolicyStatus>
}
```

The downside of this model is that if you need to change the state of a policy, you have to change it in all person objects in which the policy id occurs. So alternatively, you could use the following model:

```
type Person = {
  Name: string
  PassportNumber: string              // with uniqueness constraint
  IsPrincipalPerson: Nullable<bool>   // specifies if the person is principal or dependent
  PolicyId: Nullable<int>             // refers to a policy object
}

type Policy = {
  PolicyId: int
  PolicyState: PolicyStatus
}
```

Now several person objects can share a policy object, but the uniqueness constraints is still enforced, since every person can have at most one policy (either as principal or dependent). The downside is that you need to take care of the referential integrity of `person.PolicyId` yourself, since foreign key relationships are not supported.

Comment: Thanks. This particular project may be the first time I have used a NoSql data store for a serious project. I am struggling to understand the benefits. The whole schemaless argument doesn't apply since most RDMSs have native support for json fields. The only benefit I can think of is the horizontal scalability that most NoSql DBs can provide. But if I have a smallish number of users, not really seeing the point of sacrificing the useful constraints I can get out of a RDMS.

Comment: To be fair, Cosmos DB is far superior (especially in performance) to e.g. SQL Server in handling schema-less JSON data, with automatic indexing of all properties, including nested and array values. Cosmos DB has also some good support for very fast keyset-based pagination. But, as you've seen, there are some really serious downsides: no foreign keys, no relational joins, no read transactions, no read-write transactions, no partial updates (yet), document size limit. My team had to solve all these problems client-side, which was painful.

Comment: Also, your uniqueness constraint across both `PrincipalPerson` and `PolicyDependants` wouldn't be so easy to enforce in an RDBMS either.

Comment: In a RDBMS the uniqueness constraint is easy with a `Person` table with unique `PassportNumber`, and a foreign on `Policy.Principal` to `Person`, and a mapping table for dependents. But then you have to deal with the impedance mismatch. Noted on the Cosmos advantages though.